# Copy value from struct with different types to an 1-Byte values array

Tags: c, arrays, struct

let's say I have a struct:

```
typedef struct 
{
   uint8 value_A
   uint32 value_B
   uint32 value_C
   uint8 value_D
   3ByteType value_E
} myStructure_t 
/*Struct has 13 bytes*/

myStructure_t myStruct;
```

The struct is filled with values at a certain point....

I want to have an array with 13 byte - Values which represents the values from the struct

```
uint8 array_8ByteElements[13] = {0};

   for (uint8 idx = 0; idx <= 12; idx++)
   {
      array_8ByteElements[idx] = ??
   }
```

where array_8ByteElements[0] = myStruct.value_A

What is the fastest way to achieve this?

Comment: I don't think I understand this question. How are you expecting the 13 bytes to fit into 1 byte?

Comment: `uint8 array_8ByteElements[] = {0};` defines an array of only a *single* byte. And the loop you have iterates over *14* elements.

Comment: As for what I think the problem is, please read about [`memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy). But also please read [Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member) I'll bet you anything that `sizeof(myStructure_t) != 13`!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a union:

```
#pragma pack(push,1)

typedef struct 
{
   uint8 value_A;
   uint32 value_B;
   uint32 value_C;
   uint8 value_D;
   b3ByteType value_E;
} myStructure_t;

typedef union {
    myStructure_t T;
    unsigned char B[sizeof(myStructure_t)];
} myUnion_t;

#pragma pack(pop)
```

Because of alignment, the pragmas `pack` set the alignment to 1 byte and after the definition sets it back to the default alignment.

I am not totally sure this will work. See also Some Programmer Dude's reference to [Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member)

It may require you to redefine the order of data elements in the struct so it adheres to alignment requirements. It may require you to explicitly insert padding bytes.

Comment: There is 24 bit padding between `value_A` and `value_B`, so the bytes won't be continuous.

Comment: @JorgeBellon, hence the pragmas. These give the expected result using MSC2008.